# Is it "No credit card required" or "No credit card is required"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, american-english, idiomatic-language

When websites offer free trials for their services, they use the phrase "No credit card required"  almost exclusively.

Shouldn't it be "No credit card **is** required"?

In fact, there is no record of this phrase on Google Ngram.

[image]

However, a similar phrase "No booking is required" is still in use.

[image]

Comment: The fact that Google show ZERO, despite several websites, books and magazine entries containing that exact phrase, shows that the Google Ngram for that phrase is BROKEN. If it truly was a very uncommon phrase, then it would have appeared in the graph, but at a very low rate.

Comment: The people offering such services are concerned with grabbing your attention, not with correctness.  Crisp and concise works better than good grammar. The punchier the style, the clearer the message.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit verbs, conjunctions, etc, in signs, informational notices, newspaper headlines, instructions, etc, e.g. 'smoking forbidden', 'life jacket under seat', and, as you have seen, 'no credit card required'. It's sometimes called 'telegraphic style'

Comment: Additionally, "no (something) required" has been used so much in advertising for so long that it has basically become the expected way to say it, and saying "no credit card *is* required" in that context would probably actually sound odd to many people (despite actually being more correct).